# Update current published app(Appstore, GooglePlay) with freshly expo project

Tags: react-native, expo

It is possible to update the current app from Appstore and GooglePlay from a new freshly expo project?

I lost all the code of the project from where app was build(the build was classic one)

Now I want to start a new / fresh expo project(EAS one) and:

1. Code the app again
2. Update the stores with new app

What's your thoughts about this?
What about the implications of the parts like: Storages, Tokens..?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have access to the same AppStore and Google Play accounts yes, you could. Without referencing legacy code and configuration, however, it might not be possible to migrate user data persisted in storage etc. (unless you know the exact config used).

The differences between classic expo builds and EAS should not have any impact here. What matters is that the apps have the same bundle id / package name and are correctly signed (you must have access to the previous signing key or publish key for google play, for instance), and that all other native config items match (if the previous app supported iPads, for example, the new one must as well).